# First Alloy model on Software Abstracts, showing different view

Tags: alloy

I'm starting to study Alloy with the first edition of *Software Abstractions*, and in the first example, at the point 2.1 of the book, the book shows a different simulation of the one I'm seeing with the Alloy4.2

I'm using a Alloy Analyzer 4.2 on macOS 10.12.5

The simulation I'm getting on the execution is this one: https://puu.sh/w0Tp4/be9c6da0a8.png

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Is my simulation correct? Is the book wrong? Both are correct? There was an update on the software? Why are they different?

Comment: There are usually more than one solution on a given model. Different versions of the software or the same version with different settings might show the solutions in a different order or might even show different sets of solutions. The solution in the book and your solution are surely both correct.